# JSP no response

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, http, tomcat

I got the following issue, when i try to access a jsp page, the server doesnt return a response and i get a blank page! This happens on tomcat 7 and tomcat 8 and I dont get any error in the console. I checked my server, my url, my jsp. This happens only in one of my JavaEE projects but when i start a new one (Dynamic Web Project) and i put inside my files I still get the same outcome - a blank page! I restarted my eclipse and my server multiple times. I am using Java 8 Eclipse Mars JRE 1.8.0_73, tomEE for EJB and tomcat8. 
Here are the headers from the browser:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8088/EJB/pages/Login.jsp 
Request Method: GET Status Code: 200 OK Remote Address: [::1]:808
Response Headersview source
Content-Length: 0 Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2016 11:22:46 GMT Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch Accept-Language: bg-BG,bg;q=0.8,en;q=0.6 
Connection: keep-alive Cookie: JSESSIONID=7988165BC543FF894C8C1AC6C7428DA3

Host: localhost:8088 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: How are you trying to access your web page? You can try right clicking on your jsp page and select Run On Server.

Comment: http://localhost:8088/EnterpriseJavaBean/pages/WebBankingPage.jsp
here is my url (and yes my port is set to 8088) and i access it from chrome. Now i tried your suggestion and it tried to load directly on eclipse but that doesnt work out too.

Comment: Show us the content of your web.xml file then.

Comment: The problem was in the one of the servlets. I rewrite it, declare it in web.xml and now the problem is gone. Thank you